# Complety! map capslock to ctrl

Tags: keyboard, capslock

So I am using

```
setxkbmap -option ctrl:nocaps
```

to map capslock to ctrl since I find it easier to reach. However, I noticed that e.g. the functionality in which I hold down Ctrl and use the mouse-wheel to zoom in/out of a web page does not translate, meaning it does not work with new newly assigned capslock. Why is that and how can I fix that?

thanks in advance

Comment: I do the same thing on Ubuntu 18.04, and the mouse wheel zooms fine in Chrome with all three ctrl keys.  Perhaps you are using an old or broken version of Ubuntu, or a different web browser?  (You didn't specify.)

Comment: I use google-chrome on Ubuntu 18.04-x64 and the mapping work for cut and paste and the like but not if pressed down in order to scroll etc.